# Insert Json array into Postgres as separate column

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have created a table in PostgreSQL using this:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (MULTIPROCESS VARCHAR(20), HTTP_REFERER VARCHAR(50));
```

I try to insert JSON array into Table. Like below

```
INSERT INTO TEST
SELECT MULTIPROCESS, HTTP_REFERER
FROM json_populate_record(
    NULL::TEST_POS,
    '[{"multiprocess":true,"http_referer": "http://localhost:9000/"}, {"multiprocess": false,"http_referer": "http://localhost:9002/"}]'
);
```

It throws error :

```
[Error Code: 0, SQL State: 22023]  ERROR: cannot call json_populate_record on an array
```

How can I insert JSON array data into Table as below

```
MULTIPROCESS           HTTP_REFERER
  true             http://localhost:9000/
  false            http://localhost:9002/
```

Comment: I found the solution by using "json_populate_recordset".. Following link   https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html